# Как реализовать условие в конструкторе компонента ReactJS в es6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

В коде, который был написан на `es5`  у меня был `getInitialState` :

```
getInitialState: function () {


            if(condition ) {
                ....
                }
                return $.extend({}, state);
            }
            return {
                showAdvancedParams: true,
                size: '',
                region: '',
                showModal: false,
                window_url:''
            }
     },
```

Сейчас хочу переписать это дело под `ecmascript6`, но там вместо `getInitialState` используется constructor. Можно ли как-то мой `InitialState` подогнать, или это условие придется вынести в отдельный метод?

Comment: Таки в чём собственно проблема?

Comment: как такое условие записать в конструкторе,чтобы это было синтаксически правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну я бы как-то так написал если аналогично вашему.

```
construstor(){
    /* какой то код выше в котором определяются перменные condition, state и делается все что надо в конструкторе*/

    const defaultInitialState = {
              showAdvancedParams: true,
              size: '',
              region: '',
              showModal: false,
              window_url:''
          };

    this.state = condition ? {...state} : defaultInitialState;
}
```

Обратите внимание здесь вместо $.extend я использую spread оператор, для него не нужно jQuery но нужен stage-2 preset бабеля =)

Если у вас state и condition в конструкторе определяются как-то хитро, то логично это вынести в отдельный метод, да. В вынесении в отдельные методы нет ничего противоестественного.

Comment: большое спасибо.нет,условие не хитрое. просто непривычно видеть условие в конструкторе,потому я на этом и завис.еще вопрос небольшой. для чего тут нужен spread оператор?

Comment: @Iga, да в принципе ваш $.extend можете оставить, он делает то же самое, shallow copy объекта. Просто в реакт приложения принято не намешивать jQuery особо. (Хотя в боевых условиях бизнес разработки бывает никуда не деться =))

Comment: нет, я спросил это не к тому, чтобы оставить extend)я хочу освоиться в es6, а spread-оператор как я понял появился именно в es6, пытаюсь понять зачем он нужен( после гугления не дошло=( )

Comment: @Iga, это как раз что-то вроде $.extend. Поверхностное конструирование объектов. Выросло из Object.assign(http://es6-features.org/#ObjectPropertyAssignment) и spread для массивов (http://es6-features.org/#SpreadOperator).